# Python while loop with a single equals (=)

Tags: python, loops, syntax

I'm trying to implement a max-flow algorithm. Here's my code:

```
while path = find_path(residual, source, sink):
    (do whatever)
```

Yes, that is a deliberate single equals (=) in the while loop. The `find_path()` function is wired up to return a valid path if one still exists in the residual graph, but `None` if there isn't one remaining. To my thinking, this should assign `path` to be whatever `find_path()` returns, and then check it to see if we do another iteration. But instead, I'm getting a syntax error.

I could always do this the long way:

```
while True:
    path = find_path(residual, source, sink)
    if not path: break
```

But this seems inelegant. Is it indeed the case that you're just not allowed to put single equals in a loop in Python, due to the frequency of errors that resemble it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This requires Python 3.8's [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics):

```
while path := find_path(residual, source, sink):
    (do whatever)
```

Note the `:`.

3.8 was only released early October iirc, so you'll probably need to update your environment if you want to make use of it.

Comment: @Danoram Ya, they're neat. They'll allow for (kind of) `if-let` constructs like other languages have (although the standard scoping rules still apply): `if x := some_nullable(): (Use non-None x) else: (x was None)`.

Comment: This is useful--thanks. You're right, it doesn't help me today. (I'm using 3.5, and I don't have much control.) But I'll keep this in mind for the future, when 3.8 is more common.